# I'm testing here ways to find prime number. But it looks weird because of repeating parts

Tags: java

I'm testing here ways to find prime number. But it looks weird because of repeating parts. Are there any options to make it prettier. Probably I should use cycle or wrap it in an interface.

````
        start = System.nanoTime();
        res = PoKrestyanski.letsUseit(numbers);
        duration = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println("Time spent: " + duration + " ms" + "\n\n");



        //using threads
        int nthreads = 4;
        PrimeThreads<Integer> threadsHandler = new PrimeThreads<>(nthreads);
        start = System.nanoTime();
        PrimeThreads.Answer<Integer> answer = threadsHandler.runThreads(numbers, nthreads, pred);
        duration = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
        res = answer.isAnswerFound();
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println("Time spent: " + duration +  " ms" + "\n\n");



        //using Parallel Stream
        //System.out.println("parallelStream");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        Stream<Integer> parStream = numbers.parallelStream();
        res = parStream.anyMatch(pred);
        duration = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println("Time spent: " + duration +  " ms");
```
````

Comment: You're not measuring execution time.  You're measuring setup time and JVM warmup time.  Take a look at this [Stack Overflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423789/benchmarking-inside-java-code) for more information about benchmarking code.